# Why are absolute units with media queries the CSS industry standard?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been programming professionally for 5 years now, and I recently was asked the question: "If viewport values are so good at making responsive designs based on the device dimensions, why not just write CSS in viewport values, to begin with?"

My immediate answer was that it's much easier to write in pixels, as we all know what one pixel looks like, whereas one `view-height` or one `view-width` is kind of hard to visually picture when playing around with CSS.

But it does make me wonder, why we don't intrinsically write in relative viewport values, instead of absolute pixel values. I know that media queries were made to make our lives easier, scaling the design based on the device, but that also means that you have to keep a whole separate set of code for each and every device you want to target, adding technical debt and development time.

So why is this still an industry standard?

Comment: Unless you're using more modern web components like flexbox it's higher velocity and more intuitive to use media queries to change design components for different viewport sizes. Using vw and vh has limited applications when considering how view designs may be different between small and large devices

Comment: @Asthmatic that makes sense. So for sites that show different content, based on the media query, it would make sense to utilize media queries. But if you had a specific design layout (let's say hybrid mobile apps), it would make more sense to use viewport sizes?